# How to reduce "empty space" at the top of a UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

We have a UITextView, with line height of 21 points.
When displaying it using the calculated size (i.e. - its "contentSize") - we get a field that is too high (37 points).
Trying to force a different contentSize causes the text to be partly visible, as if there is a margin of 8 points from the top.
Is there a way to reduce this margin, and cause the UITextView to position the text at the top of the field?
Thanks

Comment: Use `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` for the view controller. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931934/blank-space-at-top-of-uitextview-in-ios-7).

Answer (score 0):

`[YourTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];`

Try this... Hope it helps